# When there is integer division in PL/1?

Tags: pl-i

There are so many different numeric data types in PL/1. And I want to know when there is an integer devision, and where is not. For instant, I've written a small example that shows (at least for me) that PL/1 is very entangled in it:

```
DCL BIN15 FIXED BIN(15) INIT(38);
DCL BIN31 FIXED BIN(31) INIT(38);
BIN15=BIN15/11*11+1;             
PUT SKIP LIST(BIN15);            
BIN31=BIN31/11*11+1;             
PUT SKIP LIST(BIN31);
```

Output is:

```
   38     
        34
```

How it even can be 38??? I've expected 34, may be 39, but defenetly not 38!!!
So can somebody explain me what is wrong with this particular example, and in a whole when I have integer division, and when not?
Thanks.

UPD:

Compiler's output:

```
    15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       V3.R4.M0 (Built:20050114)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     1
-                     Options Specified
0  Install:
0  Command: MACRO,S,X,A,AG,LC(64),MAP,LANGLVL(SPROG),NOF,,LIST
0  Install:
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     2
0 Compiler Source
0  Line.File
0     1.1      /*process rules(nolaxdcl);    */
      2.1      MAINP:PROC OPTIONS(MAIN);
      3.1
      4.1      DCL BIN15 FIXED BIN(15) INIT(38);
      5.1      DCL BIN31 FIXED BIN(31) INIT(38);
      6.1      BIN15=BIN15/11*11+1;
      7.1      PUT SKIP LIST(BIN15);
      8.1      BIN31=BIN31/11*11+1;
      9.1      PUT SKIP LIST(BIN31);
     10.1
     11.1      END MAINP;
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     3
-                    Attribute/Xref Table
-     Line.File Identifier                      Attributes
0        4.1    BIN15                           AUTOMATIC FIXED BIN(15,0) INITIAL
                                                Refs: 6.1 7.1
                                                Sets: 6.1
         5.1    BIN31                           AUTOMATIC FIXED BIN(31,0) INITIAL
                                                Refs: 8.1 9.1
                                                Sets: 8.1
         2.1    MAINP                           CONSTANT EXTERNAL
                                                ENTRY()
       +++++++  SYSPRINT                        CONSTANT EXTERNAL FILE STREAM
                                                OUTPUT PRINT
                                                Refs: 7.1 9.1
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     4
-                     Block Name List
0    Number  Name
0         1  MAINP
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     5    

 OFFSET OBJECT CODE        LINE#  FILE#    P S E U D O   A S S E M B L Y   L I S T I N G                                            

                           Timestamp and Version Information
 000000  F2F0  F1F8                                       =C'2018'           Compiled Year
 000004  F0F1  F1F2                                       =C'0112'           Compiled Date MMDD
 000008  F1F2  F2F1  F3F1                                 =C'122131'         Compiled Time HHMMSS
 00000E  F0F3  F0F4  F0F0                                 =C'030400'         Compiler Version

 000014  0028  ****                                       Service String
                           Timestamp and Version End

15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)  : MAINP             2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     6    

 OFFSET OBJECT CODE        LINE#  FILE#    P S E U D O   A S S E M B L Y   L I S T I N G                                            

 000000                    000002 |        MAINP    DS    0D
 000000  47F0  F022        000002 |                 B     34(,r15)
 000004  01C3C5C5                                         CEE eyecatcher
 000008  00000140                                         DSA size
 00000C  00000200                                         =A(PPA1-MAINP)
 000010  47F0  F001        000002 |                 B     1(,r15)
 000014  58F0  C31C        000002 |                 L     r15,796(,r12)
 000018  184E              000002 |                 LR    r4,r14
 00001A  05EF              000002 |                 BALR  r14,r15
 00001C  00000000                                         =F'0'              
 000020  07F3              000002 |                 BR    r3
 000022  90E7  D00C        000002 |                 STM   r14,r7,12(r13)
 000026  58E0  D04C        000002 |                 L     r14,76(,r13)
 00002A  4100  E140        000002 |                 LA    r0,320(,r14)
 00002E  5500  C314        000002 |                 CL    r0,788(,r12)
 000032  4130  F03A        000002 |                 LA    r3,58(,r15)
 000036  4720  F014        000002 |                 BH    20(,r15)
 00003A  58F0  C280        000002 |                 L     r15,640(,r12)
 00003E  90F0  E048        000002 |                 STM   r15,r0,72(r14)
 000042  9210  E000        000002 |                 MVI   0(r14),16
 000046  50D0  E004        000002 |                 ST    r13,4(,r14)
 00004A  18DE              000002 |                 LR    r13,r14
 00004C                    End of Prolog

 00004C  5860  3192        000002 |                 L     r6,=A(**MAINP2)(,r3,402)
 000050  5870  3196        000000 |                 L     r7,=A(@CONSTANT_AREA)(,r3,406)
 000054  4100  0000        000002 |                 LA    r0,0
 000058  5000  D0A8        000002 |                 ST    r0,_Sfi(,r13,168)
 00005C  5000  D0AC        000002 |                 ST    r0,_Sfi(,r13,172)
 000060  5810  3186        000002 |                 L     r1,=F'1573248'    
 000064  5010  D0B0        000002 |                 ST    r1,_Sfi(,r13,176)
 000068  5000  D0BC        000002 |                 ST    r0,_Sfi(,r13,188)
 00006C  1806              000002 |                 LR    r0,r6
 00006E  5000  6008        000002 |                 ST    r0,_Pfo_4(,r6,8)
 000072  4100  0026        000002 |                 LA    r0,38
 000076  5000  D0A4        000002 |                 ST    r0,BIN31(,r13,164)
 00007A  4000  D0A0        000002 |                 STH   r0,BIN15(,r13,160)
 00007E  4840  D0A0        000006 |                 LH    r4,BIN15(,r13,160)
 000082  8940  0010        000006 |                 SLL   r4,16
 000086  8E40  0020        000006 |                 SRDA  r4,32
 00008A  5D40  318A        000006 |                 D     r4,=F'11'         
 00008E  1805              000006 |                 LR    r0,r5
 000090  A70C  000B        000006 |                 MHI   r0,H'11'
 000094  5E00  318E        000006 |                 AL    r0,=F'65536'      
 000098  5000  D138        000006 |                 ST    r0,_temp3(,r13,312)
 00009C  1810              000006 |                 LR    r1,r0
 00009E  8A10  001F        000006 |                 SRA   r1,31
 0000A2  8810  0010        000006 |                 SRL   r1,16
 0000A6  1E01              000006 |                 ALR   r0,r1
 0000A8  8A00  0010        000006 |                 SRA   r0,16
 0000AC  8900  0010        000006 |                 SLL   r0,16
 0000B0  8A00  0010        000006 |                 SRA   r0,16
 0000B4  4000  D0A0        000006 |                 STH   r0,BIN15(,r13,160)
 0000B8  4100  D0C0        000007 |                 LA    r0,_temp1(,r13,192)
 0000BC  5000  D130        000007 |                 ST    r0,_temp2(,r13,304)
 0000C0  A748  4A48        000007 |                 LHI   r4,H'19016'
 0000C4  4040  D0EC        000007 |                 STH   r4,_temp1(,r13,236)
 0000C8  5800  6004        000007 |                 L     r0,SYSPRINT(,r6,4)
 0000CC  5000  D12C        000007 |                 ST    r0,_temp2(,r13,300)
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)  : MAINP             2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     7    

 OFFSET OBJECT CODE        LINE#  FILE#    P S E U D O   A S S E M B L Y   L I S T I N G                                            

 0000D0  4120  0001        000007 |                 LA    r2,1
 0000D4  5020  D0C0        000007 |                 ST    r2,_temp1(,r13,192)
 0000D8  4100  D128        000007 |                 LA    r0,_temp2(,r13,296)
 0000DC  58F0  319A        000007 |                 L     r15,=V(IBMQOFNT)(,r3,410)
 0000E0  4110  D098        000007 |                 LA    r1,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 0000E4  5000  D098        000007 |                 ST    r0,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 0000E8  05EF              000007 |                 BALR  r14,r15
 0000EA  4100  7014        000007 |                 LA    r0,'....'(,r7,20)
 0000EE  5000  D0D8        000007 |                 ST    r0,_temp1(,r13,216)
 0000F2  4100  D0A0        000007 |                 LA    r0,BIN15(,r13,160)
 0000F6  5000  D0D4        000007 |                 ST    r0,_temp1(,r13,212)
 0000FA  9220  D0EE        000007 |                 MVI   _temp1(r13,238),32
 0000FE  4100  D128        000007 |                 LA    r0,_temp2(,r13,296)
 000102  58F0  319E        000007 |                 L     r15,=V(IBMQOFPT)(,r3,414)
 000106  4110  D098        000007 |                 LA    r1,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 00010A  5000  D098        000007 |                 ST    r0,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 00010E  05EF              000007 |                 BALR  r14,r15
 000110  9201  D0EE        000007 |                 MVI   _temp1(r13,238),1
 000114  4100  D128        000007 |                 LA    r0,_temp2(,r13,296)
 000118  58F0  319E        000007 |                 L     r15,=V(IBMQOFPT)(,r3,414)
 00011C  4110  D098        000007 |                 LA    r1,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 000120  5000  D098        000007 |                 ST    r0,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 000124  05EF              000007 |                 BALR  r14,r15
 000126  1814              000007 |                 LR    r1,r4
 000128  1802              000007 |                 LR    r0,r2
 00012A  5840  D0A4        000008 |                 L     r4,BIN31(,r13,164)
 00012E  8E40  0020        000008 |                 SRDA  r4,32
 000132  5D40  318A        000008 |                 D     r4,=F'11'         
 000136  1825              000008 |                 LR    r2,r5
 000138  A72C  000B        000008 |                 MHI   r2,H'11'
 00013C  A72A  0001        000008 |                 AHI   r2,H'1'
 000140  5020  D0A4        000008 |                 ST    r2,BIN31(,r13,164)
 000144  4120  D0C0        000009 |                 LA    r2,_temp1(,r13,192)
 000148  5020  D130        000009 |                 ST    r2,_temp2(,r13,304)
 00014C  4010  D0EC        000009 |                 STH   r1,_temp1(,r13,236)
 000150  5810  6004        000009 |                 L     r1,SYSPRINT(,r6,4)
 000154  5010  D12C        000009 |                 ST    r1,_temp2(,r13,300)
 000158  5000  D0C0        000009 |                 ST    r0,_temp1(,r13,192)
 00015C  4100  D128        000009 |                 LA    r0,_temp2(,r13,296)
 000160  58F0  319A        000009 |                 L     r15,=V(IBMQOFNT)(,r3,410)
 000164  4110  D098        000009 |                 LA    r1,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 000168  5000  D098        000009 |                 ST    r0,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 00016C  05EF              000009 |                 BALR  r14,r15
 00016E  4100  7018        000009 |                 LA    r0,'....'(,r7,24)
 000172  5000  D0D8        000009 |                 ST    r0,_temp1(,r13,216)
 000176  4100  D0A4        000009 |                 LA    r0,BIN31(,r13,164)
 00017A  5000  D0D4        000009 |                 ST    r0,_temp1(,r13,212)
 00017E  9220  D0EE        000009 |                 MVI   _temp1(r13,238),32
 000182  4100  D128        000009 |                 LA    r0,_temp2(,r13,296)
 000186  58F0  319E        000009 |                 L     r15,=V(IBMQOFPT)(,r3,414)
 00018A  4110  D098        000009 |                 LA    r1,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 00018E  5000  D098        000009 |                 ST    r0,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 000192  05EF              000009 |                 BALR  r14,r15
 000194  9201  D0EE        000009 |                 MVI   _temp1(r13,238),1
 000198  4100  D128        000009 |                 LA    r0,_temp2(,r13,296)
 00019C  58F0  319E        000009 |                 L     r15,=V(IBMQOFPT)(,r3,414)
 0001A0  4110  D098        000009 |                 LA    r1,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 0001A4  5000  D098        000009 |                 ST    r0,#MX_TEMP1(,r13,152)
 0001A8  05EF              000009 |                 BALR  r14,r15
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)  : MAINP             2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     8    

 OFFSET OBJECT CODE        LINE#  FILE#    P S E U D O   A S S E M B L Y   L I S T I N G                                            

 0001AA                    000011 |        @1L1     DS    0H
 0001AA  58F0  31A2        000011 |                 L     r15,=V(IBMQEFSH)(,r3,418)
 0001AE  05EF              000011 |                 BALR  r14,r15
 0001B0                    000011 |        @1L2     DS    0H

 0001B0                    Start of Epilog
 0001B0  58D0  D004        000011 |                 L     r13,4(,r13)
 0001B4  58E0  D00C        000011 |                 L     r14,12(,r13)
 0001B8  9827  D01C        000011 |                 LM    r2,r7,28(r13)
 0001BC  051E              000011 |                 BALR  r1,r14
 0001BE  0707              000011 |                 NOPR  7

 0001C0                    Start of Literals
 0001C0  00180180                                         =F'1573248'    
 0001C4  0000000B                                         =F'11'         
 0001C8  00010000                                         =F'65536'      
 0001CC  00000000                                         =A(**MAINP2)
 0001D0  00000220                                         =A(@CONSTANT_AREA)
 0001D4  00000000                                         =V(IBMQOFNT)
 0001D8  00000000                                         =V(IBMQOFPT)
 0001DC  00000000                                         =V(IBMQEFSH)
 0001E0                    End of Literals

                           ***   General purpose registers used: 1111111100001111
                           ***   Floating point  registers used: 1111111100000000
                           ***   Size of register spill area: 512(max) 0(used)
                           ***   Size of dynamic storage: 320
                           ***   Size of executable code: 448
                           ***   CSECT Offset: 64 : 0x40

                           Constant Area
 000000  0008E2E8 E2D7D9C9 D5E30000 0005D4C1    |..SYSPRINT....MA|                                                                  
 000010  C9D5D700 00000F80 00001F80             |INP.........    |                                                                  
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page     9    

 OFFSET OBJECT CODE        LINE#  FILE#    P S E U D O   A S S E M B L Y   L I S T I N G                                            

                           PPA1: Entry Point Constants
 000000  1CCEA166                                         =F'483303782'      Flags
 000004  00000240                                         =A(PPA2-MAINP)
 000008  00000000                                         =F'0'              No PPA3
 00000C  00000000                                         =F'0'              No EPD
 000010  FFC00000                                         =F'-4194304'       Register save mask
 000014  40000000                                         =F'1073741824'     Member flags
 000018  90                                               =AL1(144)          Flags
 000019  000000                                           =AL3(0)            Callee's DSA use/8
 00001C  0040                                             =H'64'             Flags
 00001E  0012                                             =H'18'             Offset/2 to CDL
 000020  D00000A8                                         =F'-805306200'     State variable location
 000024  500000E0                                         =F'1342177504'     CDL function length/2
 000028  FFFFFE00                                         =F'-512'           CDL function EP offset
 00002C  38260000                                         =F'942014464'      CDL prolog
 000030  400800D8                                         =F'1074266328'     CDL epilog
 000034  00000000                                         =F'0'              CDL end
 000038  0005  ****                                       AL2(5),C'MAINP'
                           PPA1 End

                           PPA2: Compile Unit Block
 000000  0B00  3203                                       =F'184562179'      Flags
 000004  FFFF  FD80                                       =A(CEESTART-PPA2)
 000008  0000  0000                                       =F'0'              No PPA4
 00000C  FFFF  FD80                                       =A(TIMESTMP-PPA2)
 000010  0000  0000                                       =F'0'              No primary
 000014  0200  0000                                       =F'33554432'       Flags
                           PPA2 End
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page    10    

                                   E X T E R N A L   S Y M B O L   D I C T I O N A R Y                                              

           NAME        TYPE  ID  ADDR    LENGTH            NAME        TYPE  ID  ADDR    LENGTH                                     

           **MAINP1     SD    1 000000   000298            **MAINP2     SD    2 000000   000058
           MAINP        LD    0 000040   000001            CEESG011     ER    3 000000         
           IBMQOFNT     ER    4 000000                     IBMQOFPT     ER    5 000000         
           IBMQEFSH     ER    6 000000                     CEESTART     ER    7 000000         
           IBMPOFCX     ER    8 000000                     CEEMAIN      SD    9 000000   00000C
           IBMPINPL     ER   10 000000                     MAINP        ER   11 000000         
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page    11    

                             E X T E R N A L   S Y M B O L   C R O S S   R E F E R E N C E                                          

           ORIGINAL NAME                                   EXTERNAL SYMBOL NAME                                                     

           **MAINP1                                        **MAINP1                                                                 
           **MAINP2                                        **MAINP2                                                                 
           MAINP                                           MAINP                                                                    
           CEESG011                                        CEESG011                                                                 
           IBMQOFNT                                        IBMQOFNT                                                                 
           IBMQOFPT                                        IBMQOFPT                                                                 
           IBMQEFSH                                        IBMQEFSH                                                                 
           CEESTART                                        CEESTART                                                                 
           IBMPOFCX                                        IBMPOFCX                                                                 
           CEEMAIN                                         CEEMAIN                                                                  
           IBMPINPL                                        IBMPINPL                                                                 
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page    12    

                                * * * * *   S T O R A G E   O F F S E T   L I S T I N G   * * * * *                                 

 IDENTIFIER          DEFINITION      ATTRIBUTES                                                                                     
                                     <SEQNBR>-<FILE NO>:<FILE LINE NO>                                                              

 BIN15               1-1:4           Class = automatic,           Location = 160 : 0xA0(r13),                   Length = 2          

 BIN31               1-1:5           Class = automatic,           Location = 164 : 0xA4(r13),                   Length = 4          

                          * * * * *   E N D   O F   S T O R A G E   O F F S E T   L I S T I N G   * * * * *
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page    13    

                                            * * * * *   S T A T I C     M A P   * * * * *                                           

 OFFSET (HEX)   LENGTH (HEX)   NAME                                                                                                 

           0              4    _Anchor_4                                                                                            
           4              4    SYSPRINT                                                                                             
           8             18    _Pfo_4                                                                                               
          20             38    _Sib                                                                                                 

                            * * * * *   E N D     O F     S T A T I C     M A P   * * * * *

                              * * * * *   E N D   O F   C O M P I L A T I O N   * * * * *
15655-H31  IBM(R) Enterprise PL/I for z/OS       /*process rules(nolaxdcl)                      2018.01.12 12:21:31   Page    14
- File Reference Table
0   File    Included From  Name
0      1                   SHCHER.TEST.PLI(FIRST1)
- Component    Return Code    Messages (Total/Suppressed)    Time
0 MACRO            0                0  /  0                   0 secs
  Compiler         0                1  /  1                   1 secs
0 End of compilation of MAINP
```

Comment: Assuming IBM z/OS. It's late evening here, I'll look tomorrow. But I am curious what assembler code is generated. Please add the LIST compiler option, and also the list of the compiler options used.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr Thanks for response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficult point about your question is that the results depend on the compile-options used (at least with Enterprise PL/I 4.5  which we are using).

Under RULES(ANS) it is using integer-division as expected and both expressions evaluate to 34.

Under RULES(IBM) it is using neither integer nor floating-point division but fixed-point binary division with a scale factor!

The full table of datatype-conversions in arithmetic expressions can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSY2V3_5.2.0/com.ibm.ent.pl1.zos.doc/lr/resarithoprt.html) (for Enterprise PL/I 5.2).

So let's analyze the datatypes used:
`BIN15` is `BIN FIXED(15,0)` and the literal `11` is `DEC FIXED(2,0)`.
According to the PL/I Language Reference under RULES(IBM) the result for `BIN15/11` will be `BIN FIXED(31,16)` (assuming the maximum precision for binary is 31).

So before division the first operand is shifted right by 16 bits resulting in a hex-value of `26 00 00`. Division by 11 results in hex `03 74 5D` which converts to (approximately) 3,45454.

Multiplying by 11 results in 37,99994 which is truncated to 37 before the addition.

As for your finaly question when PL/I is using integer-division and when not:
Under RULES(IBM) PL/I will never use integer-division.
Under RULES(ANS) PL/I will use integer-division when both operands are unscaled `FIXED` (i.e. `FIXED(x,0)`) and at least one of them is `BINARY`.

As an addition, here is the assembly-code generated with RULES(IBM):

```
4800  D0C0        000007 !                 LH       r0,BIN15(,r13,192)  
EB40  0010  00DF  000007 !                 SLLK     r4,r0,16            
8E40  0020        000007 !                 SRDA     r4,32               
4100  000B        000007 !                 LA       r0,11               
1D40              000007 !                 DR       r4,r0               
1805              000007 !                 LR       r0,r5               
A70C  000B        000007 !                 MHI      r0,H'11'            
C20B  0001  0000  000007 !                 ALFI     r0,F'65536'         
5000  D164        000007 !                 ST       r0,_temp5(,r13,356) 
EB10  001F  00DC  000007 !                 SRAK     r1,r0,31            
8810  0010        000007 !                 SRL      r1,16               
1E01              000007 !                 ALR      r0,r1               
8A00  0010        000007 !                 SRA      r0,16               
B927  0000        000007 !                 LHR      r0,r0               
4000  D0C0        000007 !                 STH      r0,BIN15(,r13,192)
```

and here with RULES(ANS):

```
4840  D0C0        000007 !                 LH       r4,BIN15(,r13,192)   
8E40  0020        000007 !                 SRDA     r4,32                
4100  000B        000007 !                 LA       r0,11                
1D40              000007 !                 DR       r4,r0                
1805              000007 !                 LR       r0,r5                
B927  0000        000007 !                 LHR      r0,r0                
A70C  000B        000007 !                 MHI      r0,H'11'             
A70A  0001        000007 !                 AHI      r0,H'1'              
B927  0000        000007 !                 LHR      r0,r0                
4000  D0C0        000007 !                 STH      r0,BIN15(,r13,192)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Will try to understand now :)

Comment: AFAIK shifted right by 16 bits results in '0260';
so arethmetic is this:
'0260' / 'B' = '0037';
'0037' * 'B' = '25D' witch is 605 but after multiplication by 16, so 605/16=37;
37+1 =38;
so the problem is that '0037' is not accurate result of devision;
Am I right?

Comment: It is not multiplied by 16, it is shifiting left by 16 bits, i.e. multiplying with 2^16 = 16^4 which is 4 hex-digits. I messed up there a bit but corrected it now. But the general insight that the result of the division is not exact and thus leads to incorrect results is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want integer division, there are two ways:

1. use the DIVIDE built-in function (e.g. for A/B, write
   DIVIDE (A, B, 31, 0)
   if B is decimal, use the BINARY builtin to convert it to binary.
2. declare both the divisor and dividend with maximum binary precision.